# How does the z-index in :after work

Tags: html, css, z-index

I have this nice css3 post-it ([JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Uum95/)). However, in my application they can sometimes be on top of each other, like this: [JSFiddle1](http://jsfiddle.net/Uum95/1/)

As you can see, the shadow of the post-it is gone (it's behind the other one).
So, for the post-it on top, I added the following styles (I increased the `z-index`):

```
.on-top {
    z-index: 11;
}
.on-top:after {
    z-index: 10;
}
```

Checkout this [JSFiddle2](http://jsfiddle.net/Uum95/2/) for the result. For some reason the shadow `:after` part is now on top of the post-it. It seems that the `z-index: 11` doesn't work. Any suggestions?

Comment: You need to give it a position value. After that, you can also try giving the `:after` an z-index of -1. The normal selector doesnt need any z-index that way.

Comment: that doesn't seem to work, checkout the answer given by @TylerH below

Comment: I guess the only solution is to wrap this: [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Uum95/8/)

Answer (score 1):

When using `z-index`, you create a layering context. All other `z-index`es inside that context are resolved with respect to each other, and then everything in that container is treated as a single "layer" with the container's `z-index`.

Try applying `z-index:-1` to the shadow. It seems counter-intuitive, but it will now appear behind the container element, but the whole "container with its shadow" will be applied with the `z-index:10` of that parent.

Comment: Doesn't seem to do it: [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Uum95/3/). Any suggestions ?

Answer (score 0):

In order for the `z-index` property to work, you **must** specify one of the following additional properties within the same set of curly brackets {}:

```
position: fixed;
position: absolute;
position: relative;
```

See the [Spec Wiki](http://www.w3.org/wiki/CSS/Properties/z-index)

Comment: I have `position: absolute`, and if I add this to the `.on-top` selector I get the same result

Comment: In your JSFiddle, you do not have any `position` properties within the same selectors as your `z-index` properties.

Comment: @TylerH Because it's an additional class applied to an element that already has a `position`.

Comment: In this jsfiddle I have it as you suggest: [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Uum95/7/)

Comment: @NiettheDarkAbsol In that case it might be conflicting because both are set to `position: absolute;`, but I thought you needed a `position` property in each set of {} that you have a `z-index` property.